# What is the PDF for this uniform distribution?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, uniform-distribution

Suppose we wish to select $X$ and $Y$ uniformly such that $X+Y=1$ and $X,Y \in (0,1)$

I know the following integration result:

$\int_{S_K}\Pi_{i=1}^n\theta_i^{a_i-1}d\theta_1d\theta_2...d\theta_n = \frac{\Pi_{i=1}^n\Gamma(a_i)}{\Gamma(\sum\limits_{i=1}^na_i)}$

Where $S_k = \{ (\theta_1,\theta_2,...,\theta_n) \in (0,1)^n : \sum\limits_{i=1}^n\theta_i=1\}$

Hence taking $a_i = 1$ for all $i$ yields $\int_{S_K}d\theta_1d\theta_2...d\theta_n = \frac{\Pi_{i=1}^n\Gamma(1)}{\Gamma(n)} = \frac{1}{(n-1)!}$

And so our PDF should be: $f_{X,Y}(x,y) = \begin{cases} 
      1 & (x,y) \in S_2 \\
     0 & o.w \\ 
   \end{cases}
$

However the age old rule about uniform pdfs is just $\frac{1}{area}$ and looking at the following graph: [image]

We see the area/length is just $\sqrt2$ not $1$ ?

And so the pdf should just be $f_{X,Y}(x,y) = \begin{cases} 
      \frac{1}{\sqrt2} & (x,y) \in S_2 \\
     0 & o.w \\ 
   \end{cases}
$

Which of these (if any) answers is correct?

Comment: Unclear what you mean.  You can't select $X$ *and* $Y$ uniformly, *and* have them add up to 1.  You have one variable, not two.  You can choose one variable uniformly on the interval $([0,1]$, and then the other is determined.

Comment: When I say uniformly I wish for the PDF to be a constant. @RobertTheTutor

Comment: $S_k$ is a set of measure $0$ so $\int_{S_k}d\theta_1 d\theta_2 \dots d\theta_n=0$. Maybe your integration formulas are supposed to be over $\{(\theta_1,\theta_2,\dots,\theta_n) \in [0,1]^n \: | \: \sum_{i} \theta_i \leq 1\}$?

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken, the two-variable pdf is $\delta(x + y - 1)\mathbf{1}_{[0,1]}(x)\mathbf{1}_{[0,1]}(y)$

Comment: Isn't this just the [Dirichlet distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_distribution#Probability_density_function)?

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be some confusion as to what is meant by "select $X$ and $Y$ uniformly such that $X+Y=1$ and $X,Y \in (0,1)$." I am interpreting this as: select $X$ and $Y$ such that the vector $(X,Y)$ has a uniform distribution on the set $S_2 := \{ (x,y) \in (0,1) \times (0,1) \: | \: x+y = 1 \}$.

This begs the question - how does one define a uniform distribution on a given set? And is it even possible to give any set a uniform distribution? If your definition of uniform distribution is "a distribution whose PDF is constant", then it is not possible to create a uniform distribution on $S_2$, this is because
$$\int_{S_2} c \: dx dy = c \cdot \text{area}(S_2) = 0$$
for any constant $c$. So both of your suggested PDF's are incorrect.

A possible way to work around this is to notice that $S_2$ is contained in a 1-dimensional affine subspace of $\mathbb{R}^2$, so we should really consider $S_2$ as a subspace of $\mathbb{R}$ rather than $\mathbb{R}^2$. We can do this by considering the isometry
\begin{align*}
f:(0,\sqrt{2}) &\rightarrow S_2 \\
  x &\mapsto (\frac{x}{\sqrt{2}} , 1- \frac{x}{\sqrt{2}})
\end{align*}
Using this mapping it is natural to say that $(X,Y)$ is uniform on $S_2$ if and only if $f^{-1}((X,Y)) = \sqrt{2}X$ has a uniform distribution on $(0,\sqrt{2})$, which is equvalent to saying that $X \sim \operatorname{Uniform}(0,1)$.

Note also that this gives an explicit way to sample such a random variable. Sample $X\sim \operatorname{Uniform}(0,1)$ and let $Y=1-X$.

Answer (score 0):

You can replace variables $X$ and $Y$ with variables $U = X+Y$ and $V= X-Y$.
Then find the conditional distribution $$f_V|U(v|u) = \frac{f_{U,V}(u,v)}{f_U(u)}$$ and plug in $u=1$ to get the density you want.